# ASP - How to set [lock statement] in my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, locking

I want to set a lock statement in my code..

**I've done this so :**

Set -->  private static Object **thisLock** = new Object();  --> as global 
variable.

**In my code:**

```
lock (thisLock)
{
    myCode HERE...
}
```

I have a button click event for saving the form. Should I use this to not happen conflict with IDs. Only my code, I'll do the work? Should I write another before or after the code?

Тhank you, previously!!!

Comment: No, this exactly that you need.

Comment: I have a button click event for saving the form. Should I use this to not happen conflict with IDs.

Comment: Only my code, I'll do the work?

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine.

***Remember***: The **lock** keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

Here a simple example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):

```
class Account
{
    decimal balance;
    private Object thisLock = new Object();

    public void Withdraw(decimal amount)
    {
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            if (amount > balance)
            {
                throw new Exception("Insufficient funds");
            }
            balance -= amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I looked this example, but my code is different :) I have a **button click event**  for saving the form. Should I use this to not happen conflict with IDs.